# Beating O(n!) for computing joint distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, ranking, order-statistics

I have `n` normal distributions of varying means and standard deviations (some distributions do have the same standard deviations)

My goal is to compute the expected rank of the populations in each distribution.

One approach I came up with was subtracting each distribution from each other one then finding the proportion of the new distribution that was > 0. Doing this allowed me to populate a nxn matrix (where `P(i>j)` indicates the probability that distribution i is greater than distribution j):

```
   0   | P(1>2) | P(1>3) .... P(1>n)
P(2>1) |    0   | P(2>3) .... P(2>n)
....
P(n>1) | P(n>2) | P(n>3) ....   0
```

But to compute the expected ranks I still had to do the following, where `P(dist i, rank r)` means the probability that a sample from distribution i is rank r eg. `P(dist1, rank1)` would mean the probability that a sample from distribution 1 is the first place winner/highest rank:

```
P(dist1,rank1) = P(1>2) & ... & P(1>n)
P(dist1,rank2) =
    P(1<2) & P(1>3) & ... & P(1>n) |
    P(1>2) & P(1<3) & ... & P(1>n) |
    ...
    P(1>n) & P(1<2) & ... & P(1>n-1)
P(dist1, rank3) = ...
P(dist2, rank...)
....
```

Which gives me n! time (I routinely have ~150-200 distributions) so n! isn't feasible.

I'd like to avoid solutions that involve sampling the distributions if at all possible, but if it isn't reading that highlights that would be useful

My desired result is for each of n distributions given m ranks I have the following:

```
P(dist1, rank1) | P(dist1, rank2) | ... | P(dist1, rankm)
...
P(distn, rank1) | P(distn, rank2) | ... | P(distn, rankm)
```

Said another way; if I were to sample the distributions what would the probability be that for a given distribution their sample(s) would be ranked highest? lowest? or each rank between?

Assuming I know the true mean and standard deviation for each distribution, how can I compute the probability that a given distribution's sample will be of rank n (time complexity comes in since I'm interested in knowing the probabilities for each rank for each distribution)

Comment: Thanks in advance for your help! It was recommended to me that I move this over from S/O (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69178393/beating-on-for-computing-joint-distributions)

Comment: Please let me know if there are conventions or details I'm missing; I'm a noob on this side of the exchange

Comment: This requires numerical calculations: there's no hope of a closed form solution once $n$ exceeds $3$ or so.  The difficulty is that the probability in question concerns an event that requires an arbitrarily complicated description: you have to consider all possible combinations of which variables might exceed a given value. When all, or almost all, the distributions are the same, simplifications are possible, but not in general.